# Chartist .SVG Alignment/Padding

Tags: javascript, css, svg, chartist.js

I generate a Chartist Pie chart with the following data:

```
var mapPieData = {
series: [
  { value: 578, className: "pieNegativeColour", label: "online" },
  { value: 3182, className: "piePositiveColour", label: "offline" }
],
highest: { label: "Huawei", value: "10258", className: "pieColour1" },
maximum: 3760};
```

I use the following options to configure it:

```
var mapPieOptions = {
showLabel: true,
fullWidth: true,
chartPadding: 0};
```

I have to overlay the generated Pie chart on an .SVG map.

The problem is that the generated Pie chart is centred inside an .SVG container that's wider than it needs to be. That means the positioning is impractical. If I position the Pie chart on the top left, it actually ends up in the top middle, which is not what I want.

[image]

I want to remove this extra space around the Pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your pie chart with your supplied code on the website with the example fiddles.

http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html

```
$('.ct-chart').css({'background-color':'white'});

var data = {
    series: [
      { value: 578, className: "ct-series-c", label: "online" },
      { value: 3182, className: "ct-series-a", label: "offline" }
    ],
    highest: { label: "Huawei", value: "10258", className: "pieColour1" },
    maximum: 3760
};

var options = {
    showLabel: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    chartPadding: 0
};

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

[image: pie chart smack in the middle]

I analyzed this and noticed that if I set the padding to a negative value, the render would increase in size, but would get clipped.

```
var options = {
    showLabel: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    chartPadding: -40
};
```

[image: clipped chart]

Then I increased the size of the containing element, which sat at 100%, but actually didn't take up the full height.

By setting the container element to 750px height(as wide as it broad it would take up the full width of the element.

[image: 750 px]

[image: broad as it is wide chart]

So now we have to automate this. 
Assuming you have jQuery on hand you can simply do:

```
var $chart = $('.ct-chart');
$chart.css({'height':$chart.width()+'px'});
```

Running example on the snippets site:

```
var $chart = $('.ct-chart');
$chart.css({'background-color':'white','height':$chart.width()+'px'}); 
var data = { 
    series: [ 
      { value: 578, className: "ct-series-c", label: "online" },
      { value: 3182, className: "ct-series-a", label: "offline" }
    ],
    highest: { label: "Huawei", value: "10258", className: "pieColour1" },
    maximum: 3760
};

var options = {
    showLabel: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    chartPadding: 0
};

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

If you don't have jQuery replace the jQuery lines with:

```
var chart = document.querySelector('#pie-with-custom-labels .ct-chart');
chart.style.height = chart.clientWidth+"px";
```